# How to set/clear TF flag on x86 IA32 Intel CPU in user-mode

Tags: x86, inline-assembly, eflags

I would like to know the steps for setting/clear EFLAGS.TF in user-mode on x86 IA32 Intel CPU

tried below for clearing the TF flag, But getting error `***** Unhandled interrupt vector *****`

```
__asm__ volatile("pushl %eax\n\t"
                        "pushfl\n\t"
                        "popl %eax\n\t"
                        "xorl $0x0100, %eax\n\t"
                        "pushl %eax\n\t"
                        "popfl\n\t"
                        "popl %eax\n\t");
```

Comment: For clearing, you either need to make sure that it's set or to use OR on a NOTted version of your bit mask.

Comment: Thank you WIZZ
initially i tried with "and" as below

Comment: hank you WIZZ
initially i tried with "and" as below, it was not working
                        "and $0xFEFF, %eax\n\t";
But for EFlags we need to use "andl" correct, in that case below might be the correct one i guess, please correct me if i am wrong
                        "andl $0xFFFFFEFF, %eax;"
With this change i am not getting the exception, Thank you

Comment: You're right; I don't know why I suggested ORing it... It would help lots of other people if you posted that as an answer (the answer box is below); that way, the next time somebody comes across this problem they will find this question and instantly have the answer.

Answer (score 3):

XOR flips a bit instead of always clearing it.  AND is one option, [BTR (bit-test-reset)](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/BTR.html) is another.  BTR with a memory destination is really slow with a register source, but it's not bad at all with an immediate (only 2 uops on Haswell, 3 on Skylake.  Up to 4 on AMD, though, where it costs 2 uops even for `btr $9, %eax`.)

`popf` is quite slow (9 uops, 1 per 20 cycles on Skylake).  Or on Ryzen, 35 uops and one per 13 cycles.  (http://agner.org/optimize). So optimizing the surrounding code won't make a big difference, but it's fun to find a way to keep the code-size compact.

You don't need to save/restore EAX yourself, just tell the compiler you want to clobber it with `: "eax"` as the clobber list, or use a dummy output operand  (Note that I'm using GNU C extended asm, not basic).

```
static inline
void clear_tf(void) {
    long dummy;       // there's no type that's always 32-bit on 32-bit, and always 64 on 64-bit.  x32 uses 32-bit pointers in long mode so uintptr_t or size_t doesn't work.
   // if porting to x86-64 System V user-space: beware that push clobbers the red-zone
    __asm__ volatile("pushf \n\t"
                     "pop   %[tmp] \n\t"
                     "btr   $9, %[tmp]\n\t"   // reset bit 9
                     "push  %[tmp] \n\t"
                     "popf"
                    : [tmp] "=r"(dummy)
                    : // no inputs
                    : // no clobbers.  // "memory" // would block reordering with loads/stores.
                );
}
```

Or simply don't touch it any registers: this is very efficient, too, especially on AMD Ryzen where there are no stack-sync uops and memory-destination AND is a single-uop.

```
static inline
void clear_tf(void) {
   // if porting to x86-64 System V user-space: beware that push clobbers the red-zone
    __asm__ volatile("pushf \n\t"
                     "andl $0xFFFFFEFF, (%esp) \n\t"  // 1 byte larger than the pop/btr/push version
                     "popf"
                );
    // Basic asm syntax: no clobbers.
}
```

---

For smaller code size, `btrl $9, (%esp)` is probably good.  Still only 2 uops on Haswell (3 on Skylake), but 2 bytes smaller than `andl`.  `andb $0xfe, 1(%esp)` is also the same size, but causes a store-forwarding stall and is 2 uops + a stack-sync uop on Intel when used after `push`.  `pop %%eax; and $0xfe, %ah; push %eax` is also the same size, and also 3 uops (plus a partial-register merging uop which issues in a cycle by itself on Haswell / SKL).  But it's nice on AMD.

---

**Portability**

BTW, in x86-64 System V user-space code you can't safely push/pop without clobbering the compiler's red zone, so you'd probably want to `add $-128, %rsp` before `push`, and restore it after.

In kernel code there's no red-zone, so push/pop inside inline asm is fine.

Windows uses a different ABI with no red-zone.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: The x86-64 System V ABI specifies a red-zone.  I didn't realize that many non-Linux OSes that use it don't support a red-zone, thanks for pointing that out.  I wanted to put something in a comment inline with the code, but didn't have room for full details.  If all it takes to "beware" of it is confirm that your OS doesn't use it, and your code won't ever be ported to user-space Linux, then that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

with below code it worked fine. Thank you

```
  __asm__ volatile("pushl %eax;\
                    pushfl;\
                    popl %eax;\
                    andl $0xFFFFFEFF, %eax;\
                    pushl %eax;\
                    popfl;\
                    popl %eax;"
                    );
```

Comment: If you declare a clobber on EAX, you don't have to save/restore it around your asm statement.  `asm("blah blah using %%eax extended-asm" ::: "%eax");`  Or better, use a dummy output operand to let the compiler pick a register for you to pop into.  Or don't touch eax, and use `andl $0xFFFFFEFF, (%%esp)`.  Or for smaller code size but a store-forwarding stall, `andb $0xFE, 1(%esp)`.  Or `btrl $9, (%esp)` is a useful tradeoff between code-size and uops, although `popf` is pretty slow (so it dominates the cost) and you probably don't do this often.